# 2 decimal numbers in php?

Tags: php

For example: 
(a)123 / (b)1000 = (c)0,123 
echo c must be 0,12 

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`round()`](http://php.net/round), [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) or [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format).

Examples:

```
<?php
$res = 123/1000;
printf('%.2f', $res);
echo round($res, 2);
echo number_format($res, 2);
?>
```

Comment: Fastest comment is the most complete! :-)

Comment: nice,
how can i make a number_format rule for all the numbers so i don't have to declare every number ?

Comment: @zoro: You can define your own function: `function myFormat($n) { return number_format($n, 2); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format` http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

Using [sprintf()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can be a way to do that.